# Yeast 101: Active Dry Yeast, Instant Yeast, Baking Soda, Baking Powder. Differences and Info

Tags: baking, storage-method, storage-lifetime, yeast, baking-soda

I'm a little confused as to what are the difference between them, when should I use which?

Also, how long is the lifespan and proper care after opening of these products? If I don't bake that often can I just keep a small can in the pantry for a long while? Can they be substituted for each other?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Baking soda vs baking powder?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4/what-is-the-difference-between-baking-soda-and-baking-powder) or [active dry vs rapid ride yeast](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9355/how-to-convert-a-recipe-calling-for-active-dry-yeast-into-rapid-rise-yeast) or [yeast vs baking powder](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8832/why-use-yeast-instead-of-baking-powder)

Comment: Most of these questions are individually answered, or at least worth exploring.  I have to vote to close your question as to broad, but I invite you explore the many questions in the [tag:yeast] and [tag:baking-powder], as well as some of the more pertinent ones linked below.  If you still have a question that is more specific, please do ask it.

Comment: I agree with SAJ14SAJ, these questions together make a sizeable book chapter, if not a small book on food technology. So, sorry, we have to close it as too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note:  I am only putting this as an answer because it is too much for a comment and because the titles show.

Many of these topics are already covered:

[Why use yeast instead of baking powder?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/8832/why-use-yeast-instead-of-baking-powder)

[Why are there no recipes combining both yeast and baking powder?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/32291/why-are-there-no-recipes-combining-both-yeast-and-baking-powder)

[Does active dry yeast really expire?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2532/does-active-dry-yeast-really-expire)

[How to convert a recipe calling for active dry yeast into rapid rise yeast?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/9355/how-to-convert-a-recipe-calling-for-active-dry-yeast-into-rapid-rise-yeast)

[Is there any difference between bakers yeast and regular yeast?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/835/is-there-any-difference-between-bakers-yeast-and-regular-yeast)

[Does active dry yeast really need proofing?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/12337/does-active-dry-yeast-really-need-proofing)

[Can active dry yeast be substituted for a compressed yeast cake in baking?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4119/can-active-dry-yeast-be-substituted-for-a-compressed-yeast-cake-in-baking)

[Is 'Pizza yeast' any different than normal baking yeast?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/11521/is-pizza-yeast-any-different-than-normal-baking-yeast)

[Can/should I use rapid rise yeast for longer proofing?](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/13512/can-should-i-use-rapid-rise-yeast-for-longer-proofing)